# XAMPP gives 'Access Prohibited' on attempted access to files in symlinked folder

Tags: apache, xampp

XAMPP gives an 'Access prohibited' error when I try to access files and directories in a symlinked folder that I created in my htdocs directory. How can I get XAMPP to stop returning this error and instead begin returning the files that I seek in the symlinked directory?

Please note the following, which I have tried based on similar questions:

- I am running this on `localhost`
- XAMPP is activated, as I get a splash page when accessing `localhost`
- XAMPP can read files I add to `htdocs`, as I have added an `index.html` file which is readable
- The symlink, symlinked directory, and the subdirectories all have `755` perms, and the files I try to access are world-readable
- `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` has:

  ```
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
  <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- I am running XAMPP 1.8.3 (latest version, downloaded today) on Mac OS X 10.9

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I was able to get around this problem by using MAMP instead, but I still don't know why I had the issue with XAMPP in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain directives which need to be preceeded by a `+` or a `-`. `FollowSymLinks` is one of them. In case you need to enable symbolic links, you need to do `+FollowSymLinks` and in case you dont have to, you need to do `-FollowSymLinks`.

You can read more about the Options directives [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options).

I found another question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120035/what-is-options-followsymlinks)